# 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when selecting the sheet

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to create a csv report from c# wpf application. but getting 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC' on few machines in release mode.

The error is seen only in release build but not while running through VS.

I get this error in `sht.Select();` which is inside a for loop

```
Application app = new Application();
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wkb = app.Workbooks.Open(tmpFileName);

if (_format == ExpertReportFormat.CSV)
{
    string finalFileNameWithoutExtension = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(_finalFileName), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_finalFileName));
    bool isFinalFileNameAssigned = false;
    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sht in wkb.Worksheets)
    {
        if (!sht.Name.Equals("Images") && !sht.Name.Equals("Master"))
        {
            sht.Select();
            string csvName = string.Format("{0}_{1}.csv", finalFileNameWithoutExtension, sht.Name);
            wkb.SaveAs(csvName, XlFileFormat.xlCSVWindows, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange);
            if (sht.Name.Contains(ActiveSheetName))
            {
                _finalFileName = csvName;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Does the hosts you are running your application had MS Excel installed? Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel requires some COM to be registered, that is normally done with MS Office installation.

Comment: Hi, We are using excel 2016 and Host has Excel installed. This  issue happens only while creating CSV file. On creating Excel file it works fine

Comment: Tried `sht.Activate()` instead of `sht.Select()`?